# Mandatory return type of Interface property

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, eslint

Which Eslint rule makes it mandatory for interface property to specify its type.For example below interface--

```
export interface ITest {
name;
age;
contacting ();
}
```

I haven't defined the type of interface property here ,but it doesn't give error here .Is
there any linting rule which makes this mandatory to specify the type of every interface
property.

Comment: Could you fix your formatting and tag this with eslint?

Comment: Are you looking for [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny)?  Enabling it will cause that to error, but that's not an eslint rule so I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Here I need that contacting() return type should be mandatory to provide.Like contacting():string

Comment: But you *don't* want an error on `name` or `age`?  If you use `--noImplicitAny` you get [errors on each one](https://tsplay.dev/mMOeQw).  Is that acceptable or not?

Comment: Its acceptable.If any property of  interface dont have a type specified,i should get error

Answer (score 0):

You can get this behavior from TypeScript itself without involving ESLint, by enabling [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny).  If you don't specify a property's type or a function's return type, the compiler will implicitly type it as [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Since this is often undesirable, the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option will warn you wherever this happens:

```
export interface ITest {
    name; // error! 
    //~~ <-- Member 'name' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    age; // error! 
    //~ <-- Member 'age' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    contacting(); // error! 
    // ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- 'contacting', which lacks return-type 
    // annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.
}
```

allowing you to fix it with appropriate type annotations:

```
export interface ITest {
    name: string;  // okay
    age: number; // okay
    contacting(): void; // okay
}
```

The `--noImplicitAny` compiler option is part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), which represents a "standard" amount of strictness.  It is almost universally recommended to enable `--strict`, which will give you warnings on occurrences of implicit `any`, as well as warnings on other common issues like mishandling of `null` or `undefined`, or failure to initialize `class` properties, et cetera.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICSAVGBnKdAb1HTPQiQFsYBudAegfXjgHs4BCdU8pgP37oAPAFpR6ALIwqAI3joA5JRqL0YKgAcANmBRgo2gJ7oAFkjzokEJdaNqoRzTAB0vMkgDmdRs1Ydud18hMQlpOQVFLxg1DR09A2MzCysbKIh7dEdnNxBydBQ2aFQoSE8ACgBKeiYWOHYuHjy+ZkE29pDxJULilFKIT0UAGnQAd1M9U3RtVABrSzgYKABXOAhRbIwg2usINigkUqKRuN19QxNzS2tbDLVFlbWsp1dQAF9QUEhYRFQMHHwUAA4mw2AATYhBFQwABc6AIcDK9F86DYsyQRiC0ThEGWETgNWYaIxQR6Bz6ZSqcIAbmwwGDCaj0ZiQG98kA)